# jquery.maskedinput is not working on mobile devices (Android)

Tags: android, jquery, mask

I downloaded jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js and found out that it is not working on Android. It works well oncomputer browsers, but not on Android. On my cell phone  it doesnt accept any characters and the input stays empty.

I just have simple code:

```
$("#my-input").mask("999 99", {placeholder: " "});
```